# oauth/check_token does not check for roles/scopes associated with endpoint

Tags: security, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have one Authorization server and one resource server. I am creating access token at authorization server and try to use it at Resource server using RemoteTokenServices in oauth2 which hits '/oauth/check_token' internally to authorization server, where it only checks for token existence and its expiry. But it does not check for roles/scopes against endpoint given vs roles/scopes against access_token.

```
@FrameworkEndpoint
public class CheckTokenEndpoint {
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, ?> checkToken(@RequestParam("token") String value) {

    OAuth2AccessToken token = resourceServerTokenServices.readAccessToken(value);
    if (token == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Token was not recognised");
    }

    if (token.isExpired()) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Token has expired");
    }

    OAuth2Authentication authentication = resourceServerTokenServices.loadAuthentication(token.getValue());

    Map<String, ?> response = accessTokenConverter.convertAccessToken(token, authentication);

    return response;
   }
}
```

Above code snippet is from CheckTokenEndpoint.java. 
Is there any way to achieve roles/scopes based authorization also?

Comment: @DaveSyer : Can you please help us here?

Comment: I am at the moment working on addressing a similar issue, I have xml based configuration. I will post my findings tomorrow (might be use to those who have similar issues)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else come across a similar issue with `JWT` token implementation using XML-based configuration, I have solved it the following way

Oh and my detailed post on how to implement Spring OAuth2 using XML-based configuration can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603177/implement-spring-oauth2-using-jdbc-with-jwt-and-customize-existing-grant-flows-u/42603178#42603178)

Some assumptions

1. You are using JWT tokens that have custom claims
2. You have provided a custom implementation of `JwtAccessTokenConvertor` which in turn implements `TokenEnhancer` interface (feel free to implement AccessTokenConvertor & TokenEnhancer interfaces without having to use JwtAccessTokenConvertor)
3. You are using XML-based configuration

A closer look at the `CheckTokenEndpoint` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2/2.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/CheckTokenEndpoint.java) reveals the follow

```
private AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
```

And looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2/2.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultAccessTokenConverter.java#DefaultAccessTokenConverter) of `DefaultAccessTokenConvertor`, it is the default implementation of `AccessTokenConvertor` interface which basically have the following contracts

```
Map<String, ?> convertAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication);
OAuth2AccessToken extractAccessToken(String value, Map<String, ?> map);
OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map);
```

In my case, I used JWT tokens, meaning that the token value that I pass to the `/oauth/token_check` endpoint is a signed (with RSA keypair) JWT and the `TokenCheckEndpoint` will do a few checks such as

- Checks if the token is in the db (oauth_access_token table), this does not apply to JWT implementation as they are not necessarily stored in db
- Check that its valid JWT token in the first place
- Check that the signature of the token is correct and it has not be tampered
- Check that its not expired
- Other checks that I don't know of

In addition to the above, I needed to check that the custom claim such as **scope** (i.e. basically role and its associated permissions) is same in the database (making sure that roles didn't change since token was issued).

Based on my debugging, when the `/oauth/check_token` endpoint is hit, the `extractAccessToken` followed by `extractAuthentication` methods is called respectively (at least with JWT implementation).

Since I have extended `JwtAccessTokenConvertor` (which in turn implements `AccessTokenConvertor` & `TokenEnhancer` interfaces) in order to enhance my JWT token to add custom claims (i.e. scope) to it by overriding the **enhance** method as shown below

```
 @Component
 public class MyJwtAccessTokenConvertor extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {
        @Override
         public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
                 DefaultOAuth2AccessToken result = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(accessToken);
                //enhance the token with custom claims (i.e. user role scope) 
               //then return it 
               return result; 
          }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken extractAccessToken(String value, Map<String, ?> map) {
            OAuth2AccessToken mytoken = tokenConverter.extractAccessToken(value, map);

            /* validate the custom claims of token i.e. user role scopes
             * and if any issue throw an exception
             */

            return token; 
         }
  }
```

I could easily validate that the JWT access token has the required user role scopes in the `extractAccessToken` method. If I detect any violation then I throw `InvalidTokenException` (can be custom exception too).