# Implement Spring OAuth2 using JDBC with JWT and customize existing grant flows using XML based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I started to use Spring OAuth2 and in the process, I struggled to find relevant tutorials and content mostly because of the following

- I did not want to use Spring Boot
- I did not want to use Java configs rather xml configuration
- I needed to customize Spring OAuth2 grant flows and other features for our specific needs
- I needed to disable some grant flows
- I needed to Spring OAuth2 to use custom Users and Roles
- I needed to use store oauth_client details in a custom database tab
- Other stuff

I have managed to write my implementation that addresses the above points and now I want to share my findings in order to save others the suffering.

See my answer for the approach I followed and feel free to share your advise, suggestions and feedback if you have any.

The main objective of this question is to

- Get feedback, suggestions and advise about approach I followed
- Share all that I learned the hard way with the hope of saving others the trouble and giving back to the community what I learned from community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I started off with basic setup of Spring Security framework using mainly XML configuration.

**Spring Security OAuth2**
I did a ton of google searches and looked at a bunch of repositories including the main [Spring OAuth 2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) repo.

I started off with [OAuth2 XML Configs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/114fbd44beef0382009f207c08f0b1d9c24e95a9/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml) and I needed to make changes in order to

1. Organize, clean up the **spring-security.xml** OAuth2 config file
2. Instruct Spring OAuth2 to lookup a different (customized) user and role tables from database
3. Instruct Spring OAuth2 to lookup a different (customized) oauth_client_details table (with extra columns)
4. Use JWT Tokens and make required changes to customize the **JWT Token** to include custom claims
5. Develop custom implementation of **OAuth2RequestValidator** and inject it to the **Token** endpoint using XML configuration
6. Disable a grant flow
7. Enable verify token endpiont `/oauth/check_token` and validate JWT token custom claims

And, I have achieved the above as follow

### **1. Organize and clean up spring-security.xml**

The default **spring-security.xml** linked above comes with the following assumptions

1. Both *Authorization server* and *Resource server* are in the same machine.
2. Use in-memory users
3. Use in-memory oauth clients

I would like to keep the *Authentication* and *Resource server* separate hence, I stripped off all the *protected endpoints* configs and the in-memory user-service and oauth-client-details.

### **2. Instruct OAuth2 to lookup different user and roles database table**

To achieve this, I made sure that

1. **MyUser** object implements the following `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`
   and overrides the *getAuthorities* which return a collection of *GrantedAuthority*
2. **MyRole** object implements the `org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority`and override the method *getAuthority*

I now need to inform the *Spring OAuth2* about the above customised **MyUser and MyRole** and in order to do that, I needed to do the following

1. Provide custom implementation for `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` interface and override the inherited **loadByUsername** method to query my custom user database table and retrieve the user with its roles and construct an instance of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` and return it.
2. Create a `<bean>` of the above custom implementation and let's call it `MyUserDetailsService` and place it in **spring-security.xml** config file. Something as follow

   `<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="your.package.hierarcy.goes.here.MyUserDetailsService" />`

Just defining a bean is once again not enough, we have to tell *Spring OAuth2* to use the `MyUserDetailsService` and to do that we need to inject the `myUserDetailsService` into Spring OAuth2's default authentication provider or our own authentication provider that will then get passed to *authentication-manager* element, as shown below

```
<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
      <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
      <!-- if you encode or encrypt your password, then pass encoder-->
      <!--<property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>-->
    </bean>
```

Finally we need to inject the above *Authentication Provider* into the Authentication Manager specified in **spring-security.xml** as shown below

```
<!-- Original --> 
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <user name="marissa" password="koala" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="paul" password="emu" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Change the above with below

```
<!-- Modified with our own implementation of UserDetailsService --> 
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

And now to use the above Authentication Manager which uses, pass it to a grant flow in the `<oauth:authorization-server>` as follow

```
<oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
```

### **3. Instruct Spring OAuth2 to look up different oauth_client_table**

If you look closely at the default **spring-security.xml** from the official *Spring OAuth2* repo linked above, you will see the following chain of references

`clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` bean

**references**

`clientAuthenticationManager` bean

**references**

`clientDetailsUserDetailsService`

**references**

`clientDetails`

And `clientDetails` is nothing but a list of fixed oauth clients declared at the end under `<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">` tag.

Alright, so the objective is to instruct *Spring OAuth2* to read and store oauth_clients to/from a database. 
If we do not need to customize the the default spring oauth database tables to *meet* our specific needs, then its quite easy and the process is as follow

1. Setup the default Spring OAuth2 database tables as shown in this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql)
2. In the **spring-security.xml** change the `clientDetailsUserDetailsService` to pass the default Spring OAuth2 `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService` and declare the same as a *bean*, as shown below.

Defautlt Spring OAuth2 *JdbcClientDetailsService* bean definition

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService" id="myClientDetails">
      <constructor-arg index="0">
         <!-- This is your jdbc datasource, i.e. db details-->
         <ref bean="dataSource" />
      </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
```

and now the *clientDetailsUserDetailsService* bean should look as follow

```
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="myClientDetails" />
    </bean>
```

And everything else the stays the same. The above changes, will instruct the Spring OAuth2 to read oath_clients from the database (oauth_client_details) rather than hard-coded xml config.

What if, you wanted to modify the default **oauth_client_details** table to adda few custom columns to meet your specific needs, will in that case you need to make a different set of changes. So we have the following objective

1. Add extra columns to the default *oauth_client_details* table

given the following (in the default **spring-security.xml**)

`clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` bean

**references**

`clientAuthenticationManager` bean

**references**

`clientDetailsUserDetailsService`

**references**

`clientDetails`

We need to transform the above workflow (or chain of references) in order for Spring OAuth2 to be able to access our new customized *oauth_client_details* database table. So the new workflow or chain of references should be similar to below

`clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` bean (no change)

**references**

`clientAuthenticationManager` bean (no change)

**references**

`clientDetailsUserDetailsService` (to be updated)

**references**

`clientDetails` (to be replaced)

And to achieve the above, lets move from bottom to top. The default Spring OAuth2 uses `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetails` to load oauth_client from the default **oauth_client_details** table. We need to provide a custom implementation for `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetails` by implementing it hence, something as follow

```
public class MyClientDetails implements ClientDetails { ... }
```

Before we move on, I just wanted to mention that Spring OAuth2 already provides an implementation for the above interface meaning that we could make our life a lot easier by actually **extending** the only implementation of the above interface (ClientDetails) which is `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.BaseClientDetails` rather than implementing it from the beginning (leverage all that can be done from BaseClientDetails and add our own custom fields) hence, the **MyClientDetails** looks as follow then

```
public class MyClientDetails extends BaseClientDetails {
      //fields representing custom column for oauth_client
      //getters and setters 
      //make sure to call super() in the inherited constructors, before
      //setting custom fields.
}
```

Alright, now that we have our own *ClientDetails* object, just like #2 we need to implement our own *JdbcClientDetailsService* that will get injected to `clientDetailsUserDetailsService`. In order to implement our own *JdbcClientDetailsService* let's look at the signature of the default method

```
public class JdbcClientDetailsService
extends Object
implements ClientDetailsService, ClientRegistrationService
```

As you can see, the above class implements `ClientDetailsService & ClientRegistrationService` interfaces. While implementing our own *JdbcClientDetailsService* I do not recommend extending the default *JdbcClientDetailsService* because there are quite a few private class variables (and methods) which will not be inherited hence, let's use the default implementation to write our own.

```
public class MyJdbcClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService, ClientRegistrationService {
   //override loadClientByClientId method, query the custom
   //oauth_client_details database table and populate the 
   //MyClientDetails object created above and return it. 

   //Implement other methods to CRUD oauth_clients  
}
```

Now that you implemented *MyJdbcClientDetailsService* create a bean for it in **spring-security.xml**, in the following lines

Now inject the above bean to `clientDetailsUserDetailsService`, and looking into default **spring-security.xml**, we have the following

```
<!-- Original referencing hardcoded clients -->
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>
```

And the above will need to be changed to as follow

```
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="myJdbcClientDetailsService" />
    </bean>
```

There we go, now the chain looks as follow after specifying our own ClientDetailsService:

`clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` bean (no change)

**references**

`clientAuthenticationManager` bean (no change)

**references**

`clientDetailsUserDetailsService` (ref updated)

**references**

`myJdbcClientDetailsService` (our customized client details service)

The above instructs the Spring OAuth2 to look up a customized database table for oauth_client details.

### **4. Using JWT Token and want to add extra claims**

[JWT](https://jwt.io/) Token or JSON Web Token can be used among three different actors of OAuth2 (Authorization server actor, Resource Server actor, Client actor) in order to communicate with each other in performing different actions relating to *authorization* and access of *protected resources*. The JWT token is used by *Authorization server* and it is signed using a public/private key and the objective is to make sure that the content of the JWT token do not get updated (unless someone have access to the private key). The basic workflow can be as follow (Let's assume password grant flow)

1. *Client actor* makes a request on behalf of the *Resource owner actor* (user) to the *Authorization server actor* asking for an *OAuth2AccessToken*
2. *Authorization server actor* verifies that the requesting client is trusted or not (by checking the requesting clients passed client_id and client_secret - the *MyJdbcClientDetailsService* is used to lookup the client), Once the client is verified and client secret matched, then it will verify the *username* and *password* (this could use the *MyUserDetailsService* to lookup the user in our database user table) that's also been passed by the *Client actor* (on behalf of user). If a user is found, then its password is matched (maybe using a custom Password encoder - i.e. BCrypt recommended due to slow hash function) and if all well, then it will retrieve the User's role and construct a JWT token, then sign it with it's own public/private key, store the JWT Token with client details in the database (oauth_access_token default table) and return a copy of the JWT Token to the requesting client.
3. The *Client actor* then sends the user's request to the *Resource server* asking for a *protected resource* passing along the JWT token. The Resource server validates that the JWT is valid and not *tampered*, and then accordingly serve the *Client actor*.

Above briefly describes how the JWT token is used by OAuth2. There is a ton of more details on JWT and varieties of JWT out there (signed, signed and encrypted, etc etc).

For more information on JWT implementation of Spring OAuth2, see the official repo [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/114fbd44beef0382009f207c08f0b1d9c24e95a9/spring-security-jwt) and JWT [webpage](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

Let's see, we have the following JWT

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true
}
```

and we would like to include a set of scopes to the above token, so the *Resource server actor* know whether this user is allowed to make this request or not. The change could look as follow

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true, 
  "scope": "read write delete"
}
```

To add custom claims (each of above key/value is referred to as claims), we need to create a class **MyTokenEnhancer** which implement `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhacer` interface and override it's **enhance** method OR extend `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter` which in turn implements the default *TokenEnhancer* and override it's **enhance** method.

By overriding the enhance method, you can add custom claims to the OAuth2AccessToken. Please see the above linked repo for more details on this.

### **5.Develop custom implementation of OAuth2RequestValidator and inject it to the Token endpoint**

For me, the oauth clients send a customized *OAuth2Request* and I needed more than the deafult *DefaultOAuth2RequestValidator* implementation hence, I had to write my own and implemented the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2RequestValidator`. Something in the following lines

```
public class MyOAuth2RequestValidator implements OAuth2RequestValidator {
       //override the necessary methods
}
```

Now that we have created our own custom *MyOAuth2RequestValidator* how should we instruct the **Token endpoint** to use it using XML configuration? Well, this one took me a little time for figure it out. Looking into the default **spring-security.xml** we have the following

```
<oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>
```

When we make an OAuth2 request to the `/oauth/token` endpoint, the request is mapped to `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` first, and from there at some stage the request is delegated to `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint` and if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.java) *TokenEndpoint* you will see the following

```
private OAuth2RequestValidator oAuth2RequestValidator = new DefaultOAuth2RequestValidator();
```

Now to replace that with our Custom validator `MyOAuth2RequestValidator` we need to do the following

1. Create a bean that references our custom *MyOAuth2RequestValidator* and name give it id of "myOAuth2RequestValidator"
2. Update the `<oauth:authorization-server>` in the **spring-security** to use our custom validator from #1

See below the updated authorization-server tag

```
<oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler"
            request-validator-ref="myOAuth2RequestValidator">
            <oauth:authorization-code />
            <oauth:implicit />
            <oauth:refresh-token />
            <oauth:client-credentials />
            <oauth:password />
        </oauth:authorization-server>
```

And that's it. Now, every time the *TokenEndpoint* is hit, it will use our custom validator instead of default one.

### **6. Disable a grant flow**

We might not use all of the available grant flows hence, make sense to disable those not used. Let's say, I don't want to use **refresh-token** grant flow (just an example) and to disable it we have to update the `<oauth:authorization-server>`

The authorization server with disabled *refresh-token* grant flow looks as follow

You can also disable other flows. Obviously you can get away with not disabling it because, if you do not support let's say **Authorization Code grant flow** then simply do not register an oauth_client that has a value of *authorization_code* in it's oauth_client_table (if default oauth table)'s **authorized_grant_types** column.

Also to share with you an experience that helped me understand Spring OAuth2, I actually debugged the Spring OAuth2 classes to understand how each workflow worked and kept track of all the classes that got hit during different grant flows. It's helpful to give you an overall understanding of how Spring OAuth2 works and then it will become less painful to implement your own OAuth2 implementation on top of Spring OAuth2.

### **7. Enable Verify token endpoint and Validate JWT Custom claims**

If the Resource and Authorization server are not in the same server and not sharing the same database, then **Resource server** requires to double check with **Authorization server** after it receives a request for a resource to make sure that the token is still valid (this is useful when tokens don't expire too soon) and has the right permissions/claims. In order to achieve this Spring OAuth provides **Check Token Endpoint** that can be enabled by adding the following

```
check-token-enabled="true"
```

to the `<oauth:authorization-server ...>` element in the XML configuration file. Once the above is added, a POST request to `{server-url}/oauth/check_token` with a form parameter with key `token` and value `JWT access token` will instruct the Authorization server to validate that the token is valid. The default implementation does the default checks such as

- Expiry date
- Signature verification
- Etc

And you will have to do a little bit of customization to validate your custom claims. See my other post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809746/oauth-check-token-does-not-check-for-roles-scopes-associated-with-endpoint/42964995) for more details.